# Random() In MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, random

Is it possible to retrieve random rows from table X where flags==0?
Using MySql and C#

Comment: Do you want to return a random number of rows, or a fixed number of randomly selected rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE flags = 0
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

This retrieves 1 random row. Replace 1 by N to get N random rows.

Caveat: As others pointed out this can be slow as it needs a full table scan. I used to do this with DB2, where this worked perfectly for tables with hundreds of thousand of rows, but according to the link in [tereško's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792115/369310), MySQL seems to degrade much quicker.

Comment: If I am not wrong, should this line always order by first or second row? Rand() will always return a number between 0 or 1.. so will order by column 0 or 1? Not sure

Comment: select Rand() gets me 0.NUM BUT using `ORDER BY rand()` does get me completely random results (i just tested with 4 rows)

Comment: According to the MySQL manual:
Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.
So it will not only return 0 or 1, but any value inbetween (floating point).

Comment: inflagranti: ORDER BY rand() is still blowing my mind, i cant believe how simple it is.

Comment: Why? It defines exactly what you want: a randomly ordered table. And then you fetch some desired N rows from that table (it being random, it doesn't matter that those are the top rows).

Comment: lol. It does exactly what i want. But... i cant believe what great results i am getting (these appear to be very random) and how easy the sql was! :D

Comment: acid: keep in mind, though, that's it's horribly inefficient since you have to forcibly go over *all* rows in the table. For your average tiny database it probably won't matter but get into row counts of a few million and you'll surely have fun.

Comment: @inflagranti , actually, in real world the `ORDER BY RAND()` is good solutions up till 100 or 200 entries. After that you start incur more and more penalties. By the time you reach 10k entries, the query's execution time will be measured in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should never, ever use `ORDER BY RAND()`. It gets really really slow as the size of table grows. Instead you should [read this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

In case you have irrational fear of learning, here is there solution which would do what you ask for:

```
SELECT 
    X.x_id,
    X.foobar
FROM X
  JOIN ( 
    SELECT CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(x_id) FROM X)) AS x_id
  ) AS Choices
  USING ( x_id )

WHERE X.x_id >= Choices.x_id
  AND X.flags = 0

ORDER BY X.x_id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: "Never, ever" is a little extreme, but good article anyway.