# How to store a variable in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a list of 6 digit pins. I want to pull one pin from the list at random and store it in the variable $user_pin, and then delete that PIN from the list.

I have the following start (PDO), but don't know how to store the variable:

Select pin:

```
 $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ;");
```

Delete pin:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM pin_list WHERE available_pins = ?"");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You really should not use `ORDER BY RAND()` in MySQL. It is an extremely bad way to select random row from table. For more details see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9792115/727208) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946238/727208) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to execute your query, you are only preparing it:

```
try {
  // Used this method since you don't have to prepare any variable
  $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ;");
  $pinarray = $sth->fetch();

  // Used this method since you can prepare the variable. In this situation it'd be pretty safe even chaining them though
  $sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM pin_list WHERE available_pins = ? LIMIT 0,1");
  $sth->execute(array($pinarray['available_pins']));
  }
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "There was an error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Also there was a typo in the delete command. A LIMIT in the DELETE queries is never a bad idea.

Comment: "The MySQL-specific LIMIT row_count option" I would rather not teach people to use MySQL-specific options... it's better practice IMO to use ANSI SQL.

Comment: And I just learned something new. Thank you @chx

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia thanks, $pinarray still comes up as undefined error. The SQL query works fine when I run it in phpmyadmin. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using $this->pinarray?

Comment: No, since the scope of that variable is in the same method. I added a try/catch statement so you can try it and tell us what the given error is in case you cannot solve it yourself after the edit.

Comment: This works for select, but no delete occurs. There is no error produced: $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ;");
$pinarray = $sth->fetch();
$this->user_pin = $pinarray->available_pins;

Comment: Then you might want to try for debugging purposes `echo DELETE FROM pin_list WHERE available_pins = " . $pinarray['available_pins'] . " LIMIT 0,1"` after the latest execute to see what query you're truly sending.

Answer (score 0):

**Select**:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ;");
$result = $sth->execute();
```

**Retrieve**:

```
$user_pin = $result->fetchColumn();
```

**Delete**:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM pin_list WHERE available_pins = ?");
$sth->execute(array($user_pin));
```

This is the process at a VERY basic level, of course you'll want to do some error checking in between each step to verify that each query was successful and that you received the correct data.

Comment: @a.o.thanks, why is my $user_pin declared as underfined when I try to echo it then?

Comment: probably because your select query was not successful, verify that it works, and that your are actually receiving data...here is a VERY helpful link for PDO that i still reference often: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: This create Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object ?

Comment: then your select query is not working

Comment: ok, thanks. Should there be a difference if I use $this->user_pin = instead of $user_pin = ?

Comment: the SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ; function works fine when I execute it as SQL in PHPmyadmin. Any other ideas?